# Connecting cells with a dotted line in excel

Tags: formatting, excel-2010, cell-formatting, dotted-line

I am trying to achieve the result below using MS Excel 2010. Values in Column 1 are ranks 1.-through 3. Column 2 - team names with cell "left" cell alignment. Column 3 (team points) aligned "right". I need to connect cells in 2 to cells in 3 with a dotted line. I've tried using custom cell format of @*. in cell 2 but it stops before cell 3 and if I add *.@ formatting to cell 3 there is a visible small gap between cells. Is there a way to achieve what i want with excel?

1. Arizona.....................................................................311
2. Florida.....................................................................305
3. Southern California..................................................291

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in 2 steps:

1. First use ARRAY formula
2. Set CELL format to a equally spaced font like SYSTEM or SIMSUN etc.

Create an Excel worksheet with the your data in A2:C4

```
=A2 & " " & LEFT(B2 & REPT(".",MAX(LEN($B$2:B4)+5)),MAX(LEN($B$2:B4)+5)) & RIGHT( REPT(".",MAX(LEN($C$2:C4)+5)) & C2,MAX(LEN($C$2:C4)+5))
```

On D2, Copy the above formula and press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** to make it an Array formula. Now drag this formula down to D1:d3. Set D1:D3 font style to SYSTEM or SIMSUN. You will see your desired result. If you do not get this right, mail me at zakir@softx.co.za. Note the trick is here the ARRAY formula. rest of the part is easy.

Good Luck